# Why do i need to restart npm server everytime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am using VSCode for Reactjs and in the starting when i was learning reactjs, there was no need to restart the server but now after every modification, I have to restart the server and then only the changes are applied on the server

Comment: May I point you in the direction of [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

Comment: no need to restart for reactjs, it will auto compile on new changes.

Comment: @DanStarns so i have to install nodemon for npm start right ?

Comment: @SankalpBhatia something like, `"npm start": "nodemon index.js` in package.json

Answer (score 0):

you were probably using `nodemon` or `pm2` or similar tool to watch for file content during development.

on production, that feature is probably not used.

to verify this, looks for `scripts` section in the `package.json` file and see what command did you use to develop locally and run on production

Comment: its react-scripts-start in the scripts section

Comment: and did you use `react-scripts start` on production?

Comment: the issue was solved by using sudo during npm start. The thing is when i was installing node, it was installed in root user so now when npm start was used, it was used for the local user and was not able to use nodemon which was installed in the root user directory.